# Как организовать проверку форм на заполнение?

Tags: php

Есть админка сайта на PHP. В ней есть формы, которые имеют по 30 и более полей. Как можно организовать проверку формы на заполнение? Проверять каждую переменную, переданную из формы, и если переменной нет, то для неё выводить поле с пометкой незаполения? Есть ли более простой вариант? Чтобы не писать кучу кода.

Comment: Есть такой класс http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-validation.html может вам чем-то пригодится.

Comment: А есть на русском такой же материал? Я конечно понимаю, что для изучения программирования без английского никак, но всётаки пока не овладел.

Comment: Я не видел на русском. Но и сложно ничего там нет, если ООП знаете, то разобраться не составит труда.

Comment: В Объектноориентированном я не особо.

Comment: Просто пропишите required и не парьтесь. Зачем изобретать велосипед?

Comment: Это точно не вариант. Во-первых, тамкроме инпутов и другие поля есть (текстареа, радиокнопки и чекбокты). Кроме того, там выбирается, использовать ли то-или иное поле. Если ставится НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ, то поле не проверяется на заполнение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для оптимизации проверки валидности заполнения форм обычно использую примерно такой алгоритм:

1. Оформляем форму в html как массив
       (`<input name="FORM[value1]" />`);
2. До проверки создаем массив
       необходимых значений (`$FORM =
       array('value1' => '');`);
3. Создаем массив имен обязательных для
       заполнения полей (`$required =
       array('value1');`);
4. Обходим присланный $_POST-массив
       нашей формы $_POST["FORM"] и
       сохраняем полученные значения в
       массив $FORM при совпадении ключей,
       попутно проверяя, может ли значение
       быть пустым;
5. Проверяем значения, которые должны
       соответствовать регулярному
       выражению (если нужно);
6. Работаем с полученным валидным
       массивом данных либо выдаем ошибку.

Само собой, массив обязательных для заполнения имён полей можно изменять в процессе в зависимости от присланных данных. Так же в массив `$required` можно добавить различные сообщения об ошибках. Кода при таком подходе получается немного, основная масса его - собственно сам массив необходимых значений. Изменения вносятся легко.

Answer (score 0):

делать проще всего на js, чтоб не плодить кучу кода -

```
<form name="Form" id="Form" onsubmit="return checkvalues();">
<pre>
Title: <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
Values: <textarea name="values" id="values"></textarea>
<input type="submit">
</pre>
</form>

<script>
function checkvalues()
{
  if(document.getElementById('values').value == '') {      
      alert("values empty!");
      document.getElementById('values').focus();
      return false;       
  } else if(document.getElementById('title').value == '') {      
      alert("Title empty!");
      document.getElementById('title').focus();
      return false;       
  } else return true;
}
</script>
```

При нажатии на кнокпу submit, выполняется функция события onsubmit формы - checkvalues(); 
Если функция checkvalues() возвращает false - то форма не отправляется.
Сама функция checkvalues проверяет все значения на пустоту ввода, и выводит alert если какоето поле пустое. 
Функция checkvalues() проста, и пропустит такие данные - как простое нажатие enterа или пробел в введенных данных.

Comment: Серверная проверка валидности заполнения формы всегда обязательна. Проверка на стороне клиента делается исключительно для удобства пользователя.

Comment: не всегда, если валидность не жесткая (сам себе злобный если сломал, например в админских каких-нибудь панелях, яркий пример управление vps - выполнение на vps произвольного кода используя функции для этого не предназначенные (я не помню что там именно было, кажется shell inject при смене пароля админом) )