# Передача полей формы в функцию

Tags: php

В админке есть форма для добавления новости на сайт (полей более 10)
Пишу функцию для добавление новости в базу.

```
fucntion addNews(нужно ли здесь передавать все поля? например, $title, $desc, $fullnews)
{
    $title = !empty($_POST[$title]) ? $_POST[$title] : null; и то же самое для других полей
}
```

это так делается или как-нить по-человечески? Cпасибо

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно почитать 5 минут о [функциях](http://www.php.su/functions/custom/?1) чтобы понять зачем они нужны и как с ними работать.

создаем функцию

```
function addNews($title, $description)
{
    //обработка $title, $description
    //заносим данные в базу и т.д.
}
```

вызываем функцию и передаем данные

```
addNews($_POST['title'], $_POST['description']);
```

---

> То есть мне надо избавиться от
> устаревших mysql_connect, mysql_query
> и т.д.? и перейти на PDO?

Абсолютно верно

Comment: а если данных (полей) много, то код громоздкий...

Answer (score 0):

Функция - прежде всего отдельная программа, поэтому чем меньше у нее область видимости - тем удобнее впоследствии с ней работать. Так что на входных данных экономить не стоит. В то же время, когда надо передать много однотипных данных (в данном случае - набор данных, присланный от пользователя) - можно просто объединить их в массив. ([Тут уже приводил пример обработки форм с использованием массивов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/230884#231017))

Ну а передать массив значений в запрос с помощью `PDO` - очень просто. ([PDO::prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php))

Comment: Прошёл по ссылке. Нету времени вникать. Можешь в двух словах написать, как это делается?

Comment: А что там вникать? `PDO` просто удобный класс для работы с базами данных. Документация стандартная.

Comment: То есть мне надо избавиться от устаревших mysql_connect, mysql_query и т.д.? и перейти на PDO?

Comment: Рано или поздно все равно придется...

Comment: Понял... спасибо